# FirebaseError: Firebase Storage: An unknown error occurred, please check the error payload for server response

Tags: flutter, firebase-storage, flutter-web

I am trying to upload an image to Firebase Storage using Flutter Web. I have followed many tutorials online on how to go about this, but I end up with the same error.

**This is my code for upload**

```
  pickImageFromGallery() async {
    imageFile = await ImagePickerWeb.getImageInfo;
    setState(() {
      _image = imageFile!.fileName!;
    });
  }

  Future<void> uploadFile(
      MediaInfo mediaInfo, String ref, String fileName) async {
    try {
      String mimeType = mime(path.basename(mediaInfo.fileName!))!;

      final String extension = extensionFromMime(mimeType)!;

      var metadata = fb.UploadMetadata(
        contentType: mimeType,
      );

      fb.StorageReference storageReference =
          fb.storage().ref('images').child('$fileName.$extension');

      fb.UploadTaskSnapshot uploadTaskSnapshot =
          await storageReference.put(mediaInfo.data, metadata).future;

      Uri imageUri = await uploadTaskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
      setState(() {
        _imageURL = imageUri.toString();
      });
    } catch (e) {
      setState(() {
        _imageURL = e.toString();
      });
    }
  }
```

**This is my Storage rules for public access**

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

**This is the error I get**

```
FirebaseError: Firebase Storage: An unknown error occurred, please check the error payload for server response.
{
  "error": {
    "code": 404,
    "message": "Not Found."
  }
} (storage/unknown)
```

I have tried everything online that seems to be the solution, but there is no exact solution for this problem. Please help me figure out what may be the problem.

I am using Flutter Web, and the following packages:
*firebase,
path,
image_picker_web,
mime_type*

**EDIT: Working Code**

The problem seemed to be with the StorageReference. It worked once edited to the following:

```
fb.StorageReference storageReference = fb.storage().refFromURL('gs://storageBucket/').child('$fileName.$extension');
```

replace 'storageBucket' with your storageBucket name shown in Firebase Storage

Comment: hey did you find the solution?? Also dealing with it

Comment: Nope, I still haven't managed. I have tried everything I have seen online, but nothing seems to work. Have you checked your storageBucket name, as mentioned in the answer below? @Noobdeveloper

Comment: It finally worked for some reason. I used refFromUrl as shown in the edit above. @Noobdeveloper

Answer (score 2):

I also experienced this, because i did not update the firebase storage rules to allow me to write to the database

Comment: thanks, that was my issue as well.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error.
It happens when the path can't reach the bucket, which I found out means "404 not found". Check the bucket name in storageBucket in firebaseConfig. In my case, I was using Dotenv and left a space after the double quotes.
Dotenv was converting it to "" double quotation marks.

You can check the bucket name in the Firebase storage console. You don't need the "gs://" at the beginning or the "/" at the end. Just check the name. If you are using Dotenv, watch out for spaces.

Comment: Thank you @WaraoShikyo . I have checked my storage bucket url, but everything seems to be fine. As you have mentioned, I do not have any extra spaces, or the "/". I only have the url. I even tried using refFromURL, but still no luck. Please let me know if there is anything else I can try.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error because when I copied the `REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET` variables from the .env file used in my local environment to Netlify which is my hosting service, I included the quotation marks (that is, I entered `'my.secret.url'` instead of `my.secret.url`.